# Reasons behind placing power supply parallel capacitors in the correct order

Tags: capacitor

I don't know if this was asked but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer in some related questions.

Imagine an IC or a sensor will be powered and some caps are needed to be installed in the vicinity. I know that the caps must be as close as possible to the chip/sensor.

But which way below is more proper for supply capacitor places? Dashed box is the sensor/IC.

[image]

Should the smaller or bigger capacitor be closer to the device supply pins?

I don't think the equivalent ESR will change by swapping them.

And most importantly how can the logic behind explained in an easy way?

Comment: In an ideal world wires have no resistance and both are the same. But consider what happens when you replace every wire by a small resistor.

Comment: Yes I know why they are close to the IC for that purpose. But why the smaller one is placed closer?

Comment: @atomant did you ask yourself *why* you should have the smaller one at all? I mean, it doesn't even contribute 1% of the total capacitance. The answer to the question "why have the smaller on" is the answer to the question "why have the smaller one close to the IC".

Comment: @MarcusMüller Smaller one is there to reduce ESR. Okay I know that. but when it comes to placing them which one should be placed closer to the IC pins?

Comment: what's ES**R**? (you're SOOOOOO close!)

Comment: [EEVblog #1085 - Bypass Capacitors Visualised!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xicZF9glH0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The smaller one is placed closer because it will almost certainly have the better high frequency performance and, given that track inductive reactance rises with frequency you would want to make the smaller capacitor as close as you can even at the expence of the larger capacitor; the larger capacitor will generally be much poorer above 10 MHz (generalism alert!) so it's only really useful below these frequencies so track reactance is less of a problem and it can sit slightly more distant.

As to why the smaller one is better at higher frequencies, this picture should help - it's all about "hitting" the natural resonant frequecy: -

[image]

Comment: You say "better high frequency performance" is the reason to be closer. Is that because the length becomes much more critical at high frequencies like in a series RL circuit's R?

Comment: It's really track inductive reactance that is the main issue as frequencies rise. The track resistance will dominate at lower frequencies and that is where the bigger capacitor comes into being useful.